# cypress-wait-until keeps retrying even though the value is true

Tags: testing, cypress, wait

I have a Cypress test that is flaky due to the serial and heavily asynchronous nature of the thing being tested.

In the app, we have a workout card that contains a list of exercises. Each exercise has a list of sets. If all the sets are logged, the workout should display as logged as well.

So, the test has to serially expand each workout, log each set (which has to update the workout, fetch the updated fitness plan, and render the new style for the log icon) and then test that the new style was applied. This was flaky as there were often detached elements, and in some cases the log style would take too long to apply (or the response was slow), so I began implementing the `cypress-wait-until` package. The problem is, no matter how I try to structure the waitUntil, it retries a bunch of times even if the value evaluated is true, and then times out with a 'Timed out retrying' error.

Here is the code in question:

```
cy.getBySel('exerciseRow')
      .each(row => {
        cy.wrap(row)
          .findBySel('exerciseRow-trigger')
          .isAttached()
          .click({ force: true });
        cy.wrap(row)
          .isAttached()
          .findBySel('exerciseRow-trigger')
          .parent()
          .should('have.class', 'is-open')
          .then($el => {
            cy.wrap(row)
              .isAttached()
              .findBySel('setRow-log')
              .each(setLog => {
                cy.wrap(setLog)
                  .isAttached()
                  .click({ force: true })
                  .then(log => {
                    cy.waitUntil(() => {
                      cy.wrap(log)
                        .find('circle')
                        .then(circle => circle.css("stroke") === 'rgb(189, 249, 234)')
                    }, {interval: 1000, timeout: 15000})
                  });
              });
          });
      })
      .then(result => {
        cy.getBySel('workout-card-log')
          .find('circle')
          .should('have.css', 'stroke', 'rgb(189, 249, 234)');
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A plain `.should()` should be just as effective

```js
.then(log => {
  cy.wrap(log)
    .find('circle', {timeout: 15000})
    .should(circle => {
      expect(circle.css("stroke")).to.eq('rgb(189, 249, 234)')
      // or
      expect(circle).to.have.css('stroke', 'rgb(189, 249, 234)')
    })
    // or
    .should('have.css', 'stroke', 'rgb(189, 249, 234)')
})
```

Comment: This was what I had before I tried using cypress-wait-until, and it wasn't working, which was the reason I used wait-until.

Comment: I don't think cypress-wait-until will do any better in this situation. If the above does not work, then you have a problem with the lines above `.then(log => {`. Easy to confirm - `console.log(log)` and see if the correct element lights up.